# Speed up regex search in large file

Tags: java, regex

I have big files being from 5Mb to 600 Mb. I need to parse them and compare by regex. But it takes a while to compare. For example it takes the code 35 sec for 500kb file.

Here is my code:

```
Date currentTime = new Date(); 
String fileContents = ""; 
File file = new File(filePath); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
while((fileContents = br.readLine()) !=null) 
{ 
    fileContents += br.readLine() + "\n"; 
    regexCompare(fileContents); 
} 
br.close(); 
Date newTime = new Date(); 
long msDelay = newTime.getTime() - currentTime.getTime(); 
timeLabel.setText("Maked in " + msDelay + " ms");
```

My regex function:

```
private int regexCompare(String text) {
    if (text.isEmpty()) return 0;
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(symbolsPattern).matcher(text);

    while (m.find()) {
        allMatches.add(m.group());
    }

    for (String f :allMatches) {
            System.out.println(f);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Does anyone know what I should do to make it faster?

Comment: How many matches are you finding? Does it still take 35 seconds if you eliminate your `System.out.println(f);` statement?

Comment: Why are you calling `regexCompare()` inside the loop where you accumulate the lines?  You're re-processing the whole string every time you add a line.

Comment: @Alan Moore is right, you should only compare one line at a time.

Comment: The code is incomplete. There might be severe issues with the regex, but that's missing.

Comment: What is the regex in `symbolsPattern`? Please edit your question to show it.

Comment: Do you really want to pass 2 lines at a time to `regexCompare()`?

Comment: I've changed location of regexCompare(), but it makes no difference